# How to call web services in background using specific time interval?

Tags: ios, iphone, web-services, background

i know that this questions may be repeated some times but i need some clarifications so i asked here.

My requirement is I got location using my iPhone every 20 sec and update my Web Application using the web services.It's also working on Background.

I know that i will got the location in background using the Background Fetch but i little confuse here.I want to update My web database every 20 sec using web services. **is it possible to update Web database every 20 second using web service in Application Background mode?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `NSURLSession` using its task you can do background upload and download. 
After 1st request complete start timer which start the second request.

Good tutorial for `NSURLSession` is here..

[tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/networking-with-nsurlsession-part-1--mobile-21394) (its 4 part tutorial)
[Here](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html)

And check the `NSURLSession` document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)..

Its supported in iOS7+. But if user force close the application it will be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

No. **Minimal** interval when your app  "wakes up" in background mode is 6-10 minutes.
If your phone is active and unlocked. If your phone is "sleeping", this interval may be some hours.

1. In your project ->capabilities->background modes turn on "background fetch"
2. In your appDelegate

   ```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
   {
     //Add your code here You will have 30 sec. to do all that you want in background mode

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);       }
   ```

Comment: that means i m not updating database in background mode.ryt?It's only possible in active mode.

Comment: You don't have any guarantee about time interval between updates. For examle, I created simple upplication, that works in background and tweets my iPhone battery level. Time interval between twits is very different. You can see it here. https://twitter.com/iphbatterryyy

Comment: ,Thanks for your replay.No matter it' time interval accuracy.but i want to call web services in Background mode.Simply web services can i call in background?